# Getting CUB DeviceScan to work when called from a kernel

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda, cub

I am currently trying to learn how to use CUB to perhaps rewrite my integrator code.  I've been looking at the examples and code snippets in the docs, but I have not yet found an example of what I'm trying to do.  Specifically, that is to run an InclusiveSum called from a master thread.  From what I've seen, all the examples call the function from the host, rather than the device, but hint that it can be done here : http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/structcub_1_1_device_scan.html#a7bcc25e4d9c14a23f71431cf1a6b2bd5

"When calling this method from kernel code, be sure to define the CUB_CDP macro in your compiler's macro definitions."

I've tried adding this in Visual Studio 2012 by going to my project's properties->Cuda Linker-> Command Line and adding "-DCUB_CDP."   I'm not sure if that is correct, but I get the following build line :

"nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code=\"sm_35,compute_35\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -rdc=true -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static **-DCUB_CDP**  -g   -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MT  " -o "x64\Debug\Algorithm Test.cu.obj" "C:\Users...\Algorithm Test.cu"

My test code involves a test kernel run with 1 thread to simulate how my actual code works.

```
#define CUB_STDERR
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
#define NUMPOINTS 5*1024    
#define NUMTHREADSPERBLOCK 256
#define NUMBLOCKSPERGRID 32
#define MAXLENGTH NUMTHREADSPERBLOCK*NUMBLOCKSPERGRID   //Use multiple of 256

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>                      //display 2 decimal places
#include <math.h>
#include <arrayFunctions.h>
#include <ctime>                        //For timers
#include <sstream>                      //For the filename
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cub/cub.cuh>


#if defined(__CUDA_ARCH__) && (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#undef  assert
#define assert(arg)
#endif

__device__ __constant__ int numThreads = NUMTHREADSPERBLOCK;    //Number of threads per block
__device__ __constant__ int numBlocks = NUMBLOCKSPERGRID;       //Number of blocks per grid
__device__ __constant__ int maxlength = MAXLENGTH;  
__device__ double concSort[MAXLENGTH];

inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    //Error checking
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}


using namespace std;
using namespace cub;

__global__ void test(double*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig(cudaSharedMemBankSizeEightByte);
    cudaSetDevice(0);
    std::cout << std::fixed;                //Displays 2 decimal places.
    std::cout << std::setprecision(16);     //Displays 2 decimal places.

    const int maxlength = MAXLENGTH;        //Number of discrete concentrations tracking.
    double concs[maxlength] = {};           //Meant to store the initial concentrations .


    std::cout<<" ";
    std::cout<<"\n";    

    double *d_concs;                //The concentrations for a specific timestep.

    size_t size_concs = sizeof(concs);


    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_concs, size_concs));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_concs, &concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));


    //Run the integrator.
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;
    start = std::clock();

    test<<<1,1>>>(d_concs);

    std::cout<<"\n";

    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    duration = (std::clock() - start)/ (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout<<"The calculation took this long: "<< duration <<'\n';

    std::cout<<"\n";

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(concs, d_concs, size_concs, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    ///*
    for (int i=0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << concs[i];
    }
    //*/

    cudaDeviceReset();  //Clean up all memory.
    return 0;
}



__global__ void test(double* concs)
{
    int size=MAXLENGTH;
    int threads = NUMTHREADSPERBLOCK;
    int blocks = NUMBLOCKSPERGRID;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        concs[i] = i * .00000000001;

    ///*
    void *d_temp_storage = NULL;
    size_t temp_storage_bytes = 0;
    CubDebug(cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, concs, concs, size));
    cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
    CubDebug(cub::DeviceScan::InclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, concs, concs, size));

}
```

I get the following errors, which from the following post, suggest that defining this macro CUB_CDP is my error :

```
1>C:/Users/Karsten Chu/New Google Drive/Research/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Dynamic Parallelism Test/Dynamic Parallelism Test/Algorithm Test.cu(146): error : calling a __host__ function("exit") from a __global__ function("test") is not allowed
1>C:/Users/Karsten Chu/New Google Drive/Research/Visual Studio 2012/Projects/Dynamic Parallelism Test/Dynamic Parallelism Test/Algorithm Test.cu(148): error : calling a __host__ function("exit") from a __global__ function("test") is not allowed
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cub-users/CUB_CDP/cub-users/9ltP52Ohosg/uM9_RUy11e0J

I'd appreciate any help as I think learning how to use this library could really help me start focusing on PHYSICS rather than...anything but physics.

Comment: "I get the following errors"  What errors do you get?  I don't see them identified anywhere in your question.

Comment: When I attempt to compile the code you have posted, I get a message that `size` is undefined in your `test` kernel.  I don't see it defined anywhere.  I don't think the code you've posted could be the code you are actually using.  Why not post the code that actually demonstrates the issue you are having?

Comment: Sorry, I test my kernels and algorithms in a messy file.  I trimmed it up and made some changes for posting here. What I edited should compile and create a prefix sum of doubles, my original intent, but would reproduce the error if -DCUB_CDP isn't a compiler option.  I think adding it in Visual Studio the way I described worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `CubDebugExit()` wrapper from your cub calls in the test kernel.  Then your code will compile.

Instead of this:

```
CubDebugExit(cub::DeviceScan::ExclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, concs, concSort, maxlength));
cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
CubDebugExit(cub::DeviceScan::ExclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, concs, concSort, maxlength));
```

Do this:

```
cub::DeviceScan::ExclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, concs, concSort, maxlength);
cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);
cub::DeviceScan::ExclusiveSum(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, concs, concSort, maxlength);
```

The [CubDebugExit macro](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/group___util_mgmt.html#ga26211db894893b3cec946e4e537536f8) is not usable in device code.

If you prefer, you can also use `CubDebug()` instead of the `CubDebugExit()` wrapper/macro.